# MUI DatePicker's shouldDisableDate prop leading to error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
<Controller
   name="toDate"
   control={control}
   defaultValue={null}
   render={({ field }) => (
    <DatePicker 
        format="DD/MM/yyyy"
        value={field.value}
        onChange={(e) => { setToDate(e); field.onChange(e); }}
        minDate={fromDate}
        shouldDisableDate={fromDate}
        />
    )}
    {...register("toDate",{ required: true })}
/>
```

I used the shouldDisableProp to disable the date which is selected inside another datepicker whose value is stored in a state variable 'fromDate'.
But when I press the datepicker it is leading to [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg8hT.png).

The minDate is working perfectly fine using the fromDate state variable.

Comment: What is `fromDate`s structure?

Comment: shouldDisableDate prop expect a function and I guess this is your problem. your aren't giving a function but a value.

Comment: @MajidM. Wed Nov 24 2021 17:12:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: @ViniciusSilveiraAlves i tried this function `const returnFromDate = () => {
        return (fromDate)
    }` when I use this function,no error is coming,but all dates are disabled. I dont know if it is right I just returned the same State variable "fromDate" in this function

Comment: @AlanShajanMattathil `fromDate` is a string value, but `shouldDisableDate` expects a boolean value

Comment: @MajidM. how can we pass a date as a boolean value?

Comment: @AlanShajanMattathil You cant pass a string as a boolean, you should change the structure of your code which you pass to `shouldDisableDate`.

Comment: @MajidM. but `shouldDisableDate` needs a date to disable right? how should I pass that?

Comment: @AlanShajanMattathil No, its totally needs a boolean value to disable!

Comment: @then how should I specify which date should be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The shouldDisableDate method receives a date param and expect a boolean.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(null);
  const [fromDate, setFromDate] = React.useState<Date | null>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          label="From Date"
          value={fromDate}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setFromDate(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
      <br />
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          label="To Date"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          minDate={fromDate}
          shouldDisableDate={(dateParam) => {
            //your_condition here
            //return true to disabled and false to enable
            const fromFormatted = fromDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
            const currentDate = dateParam.toISOString().split("T")[0];

            return fromFormatted === currentDate ? true : false;
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

[UpdatedCode](https://codesandbox.io/s/helpertext-material-demo-forked-ohgns?file=/demo.tsx:1315-1328)

So do something like that and you will achieve your goal.
In your case, compare dateParam with your fromDate var, to return true or false and disable or not the date.

Edit: Now is adapted to your real case. Just check it out.

Comment: I have no conditions ,the disabled date should always be the date inside the state `fromDate` , how should I do that?

Comment: So you do have conditiion. Always when dateParam will be equal your fromDate return true to disable.

Comment: Can you please edit the answer and show me how to write this as a condition? I am beginner to JavaScript. I just want to disable the date inside `fromDate`

Comment: I don't know the structure of you fromDate param, is it a Date? even though, I've edited my post with one condition to you as example, check it. I guess now you can understand how it work. Also there is playground on codesanbox that you can use to help you.

Comment: `Wed Nov 24 2021 17:12:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`  this is an example of what's stored inside the `fromDate`

Comment: [Check this](https://codesandbox.io/s/helpertext-material-demo-forked-dre8w) Here I want the the fromDate to be disabled in the To Date Field.Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check my update on my answer, I guess that's what you want.

Comment: Did it work for you man?

Comment: It worked brother, but it is slightly different from what I wanted,If I select the `fromDate` as 26th November, then in the `ToDate` 26th November should be disabled and also in your sandbox, if I first select the To Date, it becomes an error,can you please check it, thanks❤

Comment: In your code, I get the same functionality using `minDate` only, I commented out the `shouldDisableDate` and it is still working the same.